# override wildcard dispatch.yaml entry with a specific path in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

I am in a situation where I have one app engine service (`service-a`) that needs to handle a particular path (`domain.com/some/particular/path`) and I have another app engine service on the same domain (`service-b`) that needs to handle all other traffic to that domain (`domain.com/*`).

I've tried structuring my `dispatch.yaml` as follows, however no matter what I do the `domain.com/some/particular/path` ends up getting handled by `service-b` rather than `service-a`. In other words, all paths are being routed to `service-b`.

```
dispatch:
  - url: "domain.com/some/particular/path"
    service: service-a
  - url: "domain.com/*"
    service: service-b
```

How can I handle this situation?

Comment: Did you map your `service-a` to the custom `domain.com` subdomain? Hm, I'm unsure if you can map the same subdomain to 2 different services.

Comment: Oh, you definitely can, it just doesn't like it when the paths overlap.

Comment: Is your `service-b` the default service?

Comment: Yes in this case it is the default service

Comment: And you have a handler for `/some/particular/path` registered in `service-a` 's `.yaml` file?

Comment: I have wildcard handlers in all apps -- in the logs it shows the 404 coming from service-b. Also tried re-ordering the routes in dispatch.yaml to no effect. Another potential source of error here is my `particular/path` is actually a prefix e.g. `domain.com/some/prefix/*`.

Comment: the wildcard patterns won't cut it (only one service will get the request and all things being equal I believe the default one will be the one), you need to make one handler pattern more specific. Try `/some/prefix/*`. The dispatch.yaml rule order matters: first match wins, otherwise it goes to the default service. Also I expect you're trying on the actual custom domain, no on the development server or appspot.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be more about your code than the `dispatch.yaml` file that is roting to service-b. For example, I deployed two services, service 1:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Service 1'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

And service 2:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Service 2'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

With the following `dispatch.yaml`:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "domain.com/app2/"
    service: app2
  - url: "domain.com/*"
    service: default
```

If I try to access to `domain.com/app2/` it shows `NOT FOUND` error message. If I change the routing in service 2 from `@app.route('/')` to `@app.route('/app2')` it works like a charm.

I think that your `dispatch.yaml` redirects to your `service-a` but the code inside that service redirects to `domain.com`.

BTW, if inside your services all your `.yaml` files are named `app.yaml` GAE for an unknown reason redirect to the default service so it's better to name every `.yaml` as the service it handles.